# How to check if one vector is a subset of another?

Tags: matlab

I'm looking for a matlab way of doing this.  Looping through seems easy enough.  I have two vectors, say `a = [1 2 3]` and `b = [1 54 2 4 6 3]`.  I want to determine if `a` is a subset of `b`.  How is this done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably the easiest and quickest way to do this is to use the functions [ISMEMBER](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html) and [ALL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/all.html):

```
isSubset = all(ismember(a, b));
```

You can also use [SETDIFF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/setdiff.html) and [ISEMPTY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/isempty.html), but this appears to be less efficient (it runs a little slower than the above in R2010b):

```
isSubset = isempty(setdiff(a, b));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do intersect of both sets and see if it is empty or not.
C = intersect(A,B) returns the data common to both A and B with no repetitions.